Ubuntu Server Install OpenVPN - "libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) broken packages"
I'm trying to install OpenVPN version 2.6.7 on my Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS. how to fix OpenVPN :
root@system:/home/sys# apt-get install openvpn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenvpnSoftwareRepos?__hstc=146867433.17c8987da61f55a0baeae124a9d605c5.1711348491093.1712111183592.1712124628507.10&__hssc=146867433.1.1712124628507&__hsfp=4110646246&_gl=1*27le36*_ga*MzM2Nzk3MzUxLjE3MTEzNDg0NzU.*_ga_SPGM8Y8Y79*MTcxMjEyNDYyNS4xMy4wLjE3MTIxMjQ2MjguMC4wLjA.*_fplc*RUF3ZEJ2cUNQRmslMkZOSHVjWFU2UkV2TWo0QmJDZnclMkJncVFSc3M5dkF0RXQ4c3FvcFRMTnJaSiUyRnN4cVhoYmlrakR3ZUFqUGY1OWRKR1lsUVMzWWJJRGhGcEk0TSUyRklvTVROY0FlaThacjFrbXVsZUNjeXJzRWxuazR0b2JVenclM0QlM0Q.*_ga_E45Z33NTV7*MTcxMjEyNDYyNi4xMy4wLjE3MTIxMjQ2MjkuMC4wLjIxMDU0Nzgz

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
openvpn : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


Your details imply you've not been applying security fixes; so I suggest you apply them asap. This link (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/) shows the ISO release date of 22.04.4, but installed 22.04 systems upgraded before that date.

Does this answer your question? How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?
